# Code executing even if the condition is false

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to run `copy()` command in PHP only if the variable `$is_no_art` is `false`. But the `copy()` statement is always executing, even if the `$is_no_art` is `true` or `NULL`. Check the following code:

```
if($ele != NULL) {
    foreach($ele as $e) {
        $album_art_url = trim($e->src);
        if(strpos($album_art_url, 'default') === false) {
            echo "image OK\n";
            $is_no_art = false;
        } else {
            echo "default image\n";
            $is_no_art = true;
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "not found\n";
    $is_no_art = true;
}
if($is_no_art === false || $is_no_art != NULL) {
    copy($album_art_url, 'img/' . $album_id . '.jpg');
}
```

Is there any problem in the logic I am using? If yes, how can this be corrected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$is_no_art` is `true` or `false` it isn't `null`. That means the second part of your if statement will always be true and that code will execute. It isn;t necessary anyway since your first rule is all you need:

```
if($is_no_art === false) { // false is not null so you're good to go
    copy($album_art_url, 'img/' . $album_id . '.jpg');
}
```

Comment: But I have assigned $is_no_art = NULL by default. There may be a situation where the whole code I posted inside if($ele != NULL) may not be executed. Then how will code block with copy() statement react?

Comment: Unless `$is_no_art` is changed to `false` elsewhere in your code `copy()` will *never* be reached. `false !== null`